# Build errors in SFML C++

Tags: c++, build, graphics, visual-studio-2019, sfml

I have been trying to install SFML for months with no luck. Today I decided to try again.
At first it didn't even find the SFML\graphics.hpp include file, but I finally fixed that.
Now I am getting a new error.
When compiling the code below, I get a bunch of errors.
Here is the code:

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

int main() {
    int window_width = 640;
    int window_height = 480;

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(window_width, window_height), "SFML Tutorial");

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        // handle events

        // update game logic

        window.clear();

        // draw objects

        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here are the errors:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::String::String(char const *,class std::locale const &)" (__imp_??0String@sf@@QAE@PBDABVlocale@std@@@Z) referenced in function _main    SFML Template   C:\Users\theyo\Desktop\SFML\SFML Template\SFML Template\SFML Template.obj   1

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::String::~String(void)" (__imp_??1String@sf@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main   SFML Template   C:\Users\theyo\Desktop\SFML\SFML Template\SFML Template\SFML Template.obj   1

I actually get too many to put into this post, and I don't know where I'd find a log file to give you.
I know probably no one will be able to help, but please if you understand then try to help.

I also get 6 of these warnings:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning LNK4272 library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86' SFML Template   C:\Users\theyo\Desktop\SFML\External Libraries\SFML\lib\sfml-graphics-d.lib 1

- one for each library file in SFML.

Today alone, I have frame for frame copied the following video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_9yem5dJt2E
with no luck.
I am getting desperate.
Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to mention - I am using Visual Studio 2019 and all my configurations are linked up correct, as per the video provided.

Comment: ***library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86' SFML*** Means you are mixing 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: That's only a warning - so it's not essential to the build. The build errors are what I'm worried about. I know what x64 and x86 conflict is, I just don't understand where they're coming from as I copied the video second for second and he didn't get the error. Thank you though :)

Comment: @KaneKeylewer The warnings are the problem. If you build for x86 but link with x64 libraries then those libraries are ignored, which is **exactly** the problem you have.

Comment: @KaneKeylewer I made a comment before but I deleted it because I thought it was too harsh. That comment was 'at some point you have to stop copying and start understanding'.

Comment: I'm trying to understand but I can't find anywhere that explains my problem. I don't know how to switch x84 to x64 or whatever I have to do - hence why I've come on here. I've googled all the error codes I got, searched through forums, tutorials and documentation but I can't find anything. I just don't get it. I'm not just trying to copy - believe me I want to understand. Also, I don't get how the libraries can be ignored when it finds the libraries when using #include? Obviously I'm missing something here but that's exactly what I want to know, I don't want people to just make harsh comments.

Comment: OK, I'll go though some concepts. Libraries are not found with `#include`, those are header files. Libraries are found by the linker and they have to be in the right format for the platform you are linking for. To switch the target you have to pick the 'Solution Platform' it's normally on a drop down menu in the toolbar. If you downloaded 32 bit (which is what the guy in the video did) then you should be x86 for the platform. I notice that the guy in the video does mention this, although he didn't show how it was done, he just said it has to be correct.

Comment: It's probably just the case that the default platform picked by visual studio on his machine and on your machine are different. There could be many reasons for this.

Comment: You should spent some time reseaching the separate compilation model used by C++. What libraries are, what header files are, what compilation is, what linking is etc. etc. Tools like Visual Studio make it seem easy because you just push a button and everything builds. But when things go wrong you do need to understand what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: You likely should have a choice between Win32 and x64 on your toolbar right next to Debug in Visual Studio. However to use the choice you have to add the proper libraries to the other configuration. SFML has different libraries for debug mode than they do for release mode and you should not select the wrong ones because this is Undefined Behavior. The debug libraries should have a d in the name close to the .lib the release will not have this d.

Comment: @KaneKeylewer I see from the error message that your libraries are 64 bit, it says `library machine type 'x64'`, so that's different from the guy in the video. In that case you need to pick x64 as your platform (or go back and download the other version of the library).

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with your linkers. Makes sure you have linked the correct files for the correct architecture/platform and their dependencies as well (in the correct order, of course). That being said, it could be that your downloaded version of SFML does not match the compiler you are using it on. You could always recheck that or build SFML yourself from source.
If you don't want to go through all that then I have a template on GitHub for SFML with VS2019.

[SFMLVS2019Template](https://github.com/Himan2104/SFMLVS2019template)

Just go through the readme if you can't figure out something.
Also, as someone mentioned, I think you should look a bit more into how compilers and linkers work. IDEs definitely make it seem easier than it is.